# Room database @Delete not executing

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to delete a row from a Room Database I created.

The weird thing is that only the first time I executed the command is when it does not delete the row:

```
App.get().getDB().productDao().delete(myArrayList.get(clickedItemIndex));
```

After the first time when I try to delete the row again, everything is okay and deleted.

My Activity where I delete a row:

```
private class DeletePelati extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Perform pre-adding operation here.
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
       App.get().getDB().productDao().delete(myArrayList.get(clickedItemIndex));
       return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //To after addition operation here.
        setResult(pelatis,3);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Then when I restart my application the delete query is executed normaly.

Here is my App that extends Aplication:

```
public class App extends Application {

public static App INSTANCE;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase";
private static final String PREFERENCES = "RoomDemo.preferences";
private static final String KEY_FORCE_UPDATE = "force_update";

private MyDatabase database;

public static App get() {
    return INSTANCE;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);

    // create database
    database = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),MyDatabase.class,DATABASE_NAME)
            .build();

    INSTANCE = this;
}

public MyDatabase getDB() {
    return database;
}

public boolean isForceUpdate() {
    return getSP().getBoolean(KEY_FORCE_UPDATE, true);
}

public void setForceUpdate(boolean force) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = getSP().edit();
    edit.putBoolean(KEY_FORCE_UPDATE, force);
    edit.apply();
}

private SharedPreferences getSP() {
    return getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public  void cleanUp(){
    database = null;
}
}
```

This is my DAO Class:

```
@Dao
public interface PelatesDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM Pelates")
List<Pelates> getAll();

@Query("SELECT * FROM Pelates WHERE name LIKE :name LIMIT 1")
Pelates findByName(String name);

@Insert
void insertAll(List<Pelates> pelates);

@Insert
void insert(Pelates pelates);

@Update
void update(Pelates pelates);

@Delete
void delete(Pelates pelates);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using @Delete use:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM Test WHERE id=:arg0")
fun deleteById(position: Int)
```

In the above example Test is the table name, `id=:arg0` is the WHERE clause
and in the function parameter passed is the value of where clause field.

P.C. the above example is in kotlin language.